# Cleanest way to do callbacks in C++ without C++11?

Tags: c++, callback, c++03

What is the cleanest way to do callbacks to a class in C++?

I usually create a function like:

```
void registerCallback(void(*callback)(void* param), void* param);
```

And then call it like such:

```
foo->registerCallback(callbackStatic, this);
```

Then I add a static function in my class like such:

```
static void callbackStatic(void* param)
{
    ((Type*)(param))->callback();
}
```

It works, but it's a pain. I have to create two functions per callback. If I could use C++11, I'd use a lambda instead. Qt has a very nice signal and slot mechanism, but requires a special pre-compiler.

I'm writing a library, so I'd like to keep the requirements as low as possible. No C++11, no boost, etc. Is there a way to build a lambda or signal/slot 'like' callback system only using C++03?

Comment: Is C++11 really that big of a barrier?  It has been standard for 5 years and compilers supported even before it was standardized.  Also it can make the code more efficient just because of move semantics.

Comment: @NathanOliver Unfortunately for some companies it can be. You would be amazed as to what mission critical operation's code depends on VS 2008 exclusively.

Comment: @RawN I get that but in most of those cases they are not going to use this library anyway as it would need to be thoroughly tested just like the new features they do not turn on by upgrading.

Comment: @NathanOliver: As someone who only just last month updated all his firm's toolchains to get C++11 support, **yes**! Unless you have a variable build environment, and unless the libraries you share across your projects can be made to build with both standards, you're stuck on C++03 until there's a really good reason to spend time migrating everything. In Enterprise, you don't change things when you don't need to; I'm sure you're aware that every change has a cost, both directly and through risk of regression. But I'm glad I now get `auto`, variadic templates and lambdas omg

Comment: C++11 means dropping support for OS X 10.6 which we aren't ready to do yet.

Comment: It also means dropping support for CentOS 6 (and, I'm sure, other RHEL6-derived distros; these are widely used and formally supported until 2020), unless you're content to redistribute _all_ your C++ shared libraries (including libstdc++). I/we decided to do that, but only because the opportunity to standardise pretty much everything at GCC 4.8 and C++11 was greater than the cost of having to mess about on just one of our target platforms. SCL helps a bit (in that we don't need to build GCC from source at least). But, yeah, in general, it is _far_ from clear that everybody can use C++11 yet.

Answer (score 4):

If you are able to start from scratch, I recommend not using functions for callbacks in C++. Instead, use objects.

```
struct CallbackHandler { virtual void doit() = 0; };

void registerCallback(Callbackhandler* handler);
```

and then

```
struct MyCallbackHandler : public CallbackHandler { ... };

registerCallback(new MyCallbackHandler());
```

Comment: The downside to doing it this way, if you subscribe to two callbacks, they both call doit(), so you have to pass a source parameter or something as well.

Comment: @FigBug, My answer points out the core idea. It can refined in many ways to fit your particular needs.

Comment: @FigBug I don't get your comment?

Comment: @FigBug: That was the case anyway.

Comment: Also, not using the smart pointers from C++11, you could end up with a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to build a lambda or signal/slot 'like' callback system only using C++03?

Another way is to use just plain old pure abstract interfaces. This wouldn't require that 2 stage reinforcement of class member functions through the *callback* function, but just use virtual polymorphism.

You could even use *static polymorphism* aka as CRTP which also works with the pre c++11 standard.

That all worked from the early standardisations onwards.

---

<sub>Code samples at [@R Sahu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39537866/1413395)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit complicated, but it works for me:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class C {
public:
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
    }
};

class D {
public:
    void bar() {
        std::cout << "bar" << std::endl;
    }
};

class abstract_bind {
public:
    virtual void operator()() = 0;
    virtual ~abstract_bind() {}
};

template <typename F, typename T>
class bind : public abstract_bind {
public:
    bind(F f_, T *t_) : f(f_), t(t_) {}

    virtual void operator()() {
        f(t);
    }

private:
    F f;
    T *t;
};


int main() {
    C c1, c2;
    D d;

    std::vector<abstract_bind*> v;

    v.push_back(new bind<std::mem_fun_t<void, C>, C>(std::mem_fun(&C::foo), &c1));
    v.push_back(new bind<std::mem_fun_t<void, C>, C>(std::mem_fun(&C::foo), &c2));
    v.push_back(new bind<std::mem_fun_t<void, D>, D>(std::mem_fun(&D::bar), &d));

    for (size_t i=0; i<v.size(); ++i)
        (*v[i])();

    for (size_t i=0; i<v.size(); ++i)
        delete v[i];

    return 0;
}
```

The basic idea is that you use `std::mem_fun` to get the object's member function and bind the corresponding `this` pointer to it to get "plain" function.

Answer (score 1):

You might keep the C-style callbacks and use a structure for invoking member functions:

```
// C-style callback
// ================

void(*registered_callback)(void* param) = 0;
void* registered_param = 0;
void registerCallback(void(*callback)(void* param), void* param) {
    registered_callback = callback;
    registered_param = param;
}
void unregisterCallback(void(*callback)(void* param), void* param) {
    registered_callback = 0;
    registered_param = 0;
}

// Invoker
// =======

struct InvokerBase {
    static void callInvoker(void* invoker) {
        reinterpret_cast<InvokerBase*>(invoker)->apply();
    }

    virtual void apply() const = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class Invoker : public InvokerBase
{
    public:
    Invoker(T& object, void(T::*function)())
    : object(&object), function(function)
    {
        registerCallback(callInvoker, this);
    }
    ~Invoker() {
        unregisterCallback(callInvoker, this);
    }

    void apply() const {
        (object->*function)();
    }

    private:
    Invoker(const Invoker&); // no copy
    Invoker& operator = (const Invoker&); // no copy

    T* object;
    void (T::*function)();
};


// Test
// ====

#include<cassert>
#include<iostream>

struct Type {
    void print() { std::cout << "Hello\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    Type x;
    {
        Invoker<Type> print_invoker(x, &Type::print);
        registered_callback(registered_param);
    }
    assert(registered_callback == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try Synapse, it is a signal-slot library that requires no precompiling. In Synapse any object whatsoever can be used as an emitter: http://zajo.github.io/boost-synapse/